# Nested ng-repeats, hierarchy and sorting

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I have to refactor an Angular project which has table build with nested ng-repeats.
There are three ng-repeats and each of them belong to different parts of three dimensional hierarchy.

First level is root and it's fields are sortable. Maybe picture below says it easier.

Level 1 (root containing fields that are sortable) 
--- Level 2 
-------- Level 3

So when Level 1's field is clicked it should sort data but keep Level 2 and Level 3 fields below right Level 1's field.

And of course :( there are no good structured data structures. Every Level's data comes in own Array.

I thing it would have been a place of Grid but now I can't change it because there is so much functionality build into it.

So, how to to add Sorting mechanism to this kind of table? Any ideas or any samples?

I have used in other projects data structures in this kind of situations and almost every time a Grid.

But now it is impossible.

Br Michael

Comment: Can you post a example of the data structure in code?

Answer (score 2):

Try Angular-NestedSortable, it's an Angularjs plugin that can sort nested lists and bind data. 
https://github.com/jimliu/Angular-NestedSortable